# Pipes, and how using them in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

I see commands like this in some scripts: `/bin/cat somefile | someprogram`. I would like to know how to read the entire pipe the same way someprogram does. So when I run  `/bin/cat something | myprogram.sh`, myprogram.sh has a variable called mypipevar equal to whatever was piped - all of the pipe text. If this is unclear, please let me know. I have read that read will likely not work, and bash may not be the right shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pipe connects `stdout` of one program to `stdin` of another, so in your script simply read from `stdin` and you will get what the previous command printed out. A simple way to read this into a variable is with cat for example inside `myprogram.sh`:

```
mypipevar="$(cat ${1:-/dev/stdin})"
echo "Obtained the value: '$mypipevar'"
```

However, quite often you want to process things line by line rather then all at once, this can be done with

```
while read line
do
  echo "$line"
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

Note that `${1:-/dev/stdin}` will give you the first argument, or if no arguments are specified then `/dev/stdin` which will contain the contents of stdin which can be read like a file. This allows you to execute the script as either `command | script` or simply as `script filename`.